# How to add a BASE_URL in an include in php

Tags: php

I'm working locally. My `<?php include ('header.php'); ?>` is working fine for those files in the root. E.g. `mysite/mypage.php` works perfect but `mysite/mydir/mypage.php` can't find any includes, all of them located at the root. I defined `BASE_URL` in header.php:

```
<?php
    define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/bmmi/');
?>
```

Then, lets say I have in `contact.php`:

```
<?php
    $title = 'Contact Us';
    include (BASE_URL . 'header.php');
?>
```

and still I'm getting an error because it can't find the `includes`. Any idea what's going on? Thanks.

> **EDIT**

Still getting an error. This is what I have now:

```
<?php   
    define('BASE_URL', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bmmi/'); 
    $title = 'Custom luxury homes';
    include (BASE_URL . 'header.php');
?>
```

And this is one the errors:
***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)***

***localhost/bmmi/portfolio/img/logo.png***

The path should be like this: **bmmi/img/logo.png**. As you can see is adding the **img/logo.png** in **portfolio**. It is happening with all dependencies, .css, .js and images. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: did you include the header.php in contact.php, for you to access the BASE_URL you need to include header.php

Comment: the problem is BASE_URL does not yet exists when the time you call it.

Comment: You are trying to call header.php with base_url but the base_url is inside the header.php so thats why it is not working the base_url variable does not exists

Comment: how about you pass the file path instead of the url.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need the path on the file system, not the URL when accessing it by the browser:

```
define('BASE_URL', '/path/to/webroot/bmmi/'); // <-- like this
$title = 'Contact Us';
include (BASE_URL . 'header.php');
```

Alternately, you could also make it relative to the directory that contains the current file, which would make your script work if you ever change the path to the web root:

```
define('BASE_URL', __DIR__ . '/bmmi/');
```

Note: If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file to be included using a URL, however the URL would need to output a PHP script to be parsed by your server. I can almost definitely guarantee this is not the case, and if it is, you likely have a major security issue because whoever controls the other server can execute arbitrary code in your app.

Finally, you may be better to just append to the current include path and save yourself from having to specify the `BASE_URL` constant every time. This way you can just include it without specifying the path:

```
set_include_path(
    get_include_path()
    .PATH_SEPARATOR.__DIR__.'/bmmi/'
    .PATH_SEPARATOR.'/some/other/path/'
);
include('header.php'); // Will now also look for the file in __DIR__.'/bmmi/'
```

Comment: take a look at the EDIT I made. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably need `include(BASE_URL . 'img/logo.png');`. If that's what you have, try doing some `var_dump`s to figure out what is actually happening and make sure that the file actually does exist.